# Rails - Javascript Issues

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have been working to make some javascript work in my Rails app all day.  I have a basic Rails app.  I am trying to make a row clickable.  I am adding a data-attribute to the row to hold the url that I want to go to, but I cant access it from the table.  Here is my HTML:

```
  <% @kids.each do |kid| %>
    <tr data-link="<%= kid_path(kid) %>">
      <td><%= kid.name %></td>
      <td><%= kid.balance %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', kid %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_kid_path(kid) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', kid, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
 <% end %>
```

I have some javascript that needs to be called when I click on the row.  Here is the js:

```
  console.log("HERE 1");
  $("tr").click(function() {
    console.log("HERE 2");
  })
```

HERE 1 gets called, but HERE 2 does not.  Why would that happen?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is window.location getting set? What would an `alert( this.data("link") );` show right before the assignment?

Comment: I was just showing that the code was actually getting hit.  Nothing else.

Comment: Got that. I'm suggesting get more info at that point, unless you're sure it's setting the value the way you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what caused the issue, but I know a fix for it.  If you wrap your js function in a jQuery .ready, then everything works like it is supposed to.  For example:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $("tr").click(function() {
    console.log("HERE 2");
  });
});
```

I dont know why this is necessary, but it is a fix.